# bash command: replace "A" to "B" file with long and all symbol letter..?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

then:

```
A=<item ok:my=world"hello/my.earth/my.land/mycity"><item or mylove:heart="myGIRL" oh:myGOD="i-love-you"><item></item></item></item>

B=<item ok:my=world"hello/my.earth/my.land/mycity"><item or mylove:heart="myGIRL" oh:myGOD="i-love-you"><item>LOVER.png;LOVER-ever.png</item></item></item>
```

maybe command: sed, awk.

i'm update my error write..

```
#!/bin/bash
replace_a=<item ok:my=world"hello/my.earth/my.land/mycity"><item or mylove:heart="myGIRL" oh:myGOD="i-love-you"><item></item></item></item>
replace_b=<item ok:my=world"hello/my.earth/my.land/mycity"><item or mylove:heart="myGIRL" oh:myGOD="i-love-you"><item>LOVER.png;LOVER-ever.png</item></item></item>
....
....
```

Comment: If it's XML, you SHOULDN'T use sed/awk - you should use a parser. As you comment below - even for long files - you can still use a parser. Please give a sample of the XML (which is complete and valid), and I'll give you an example of how to do it.

Comment: ok, possible other solution:command to delete 1 line $A in file.txt and add new line $B in file.txt?

Comment: sed '/i-love-you/d' file.txt   sed -i '<item ok:my=world"hello/my.earth/my.land/mycity"><item or mylove:heart="myGIRL" oh:myGOD="i-love-you"><item>LOVER.png;LOVER-ever.png</item></item></item>' file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find other trick:

```
sed -i '/earth/d' file.txt
echo '<item ok:my=world"hello/my.earth/my.land/mycity"><item or mylove:heart="myGIRL" oh:myGOD="i-love-you"><item>LOVER.png;LOVER-ever.png</item></item></item>' >> file.txt
```

this is good for trick?
thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Use character class `[[:punct:]]` with `sed`:

```
% LC_ALL=C sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g' <<<"$A"   
item okmyworldhellomyearthmylandmycityitem or myloveheartmyGIRL

% LC_ALL=C sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g' <<<"$B"
item okmyworldhellomyearthmylandmycityitem or myloveheartmyGIRL ohmyGODiloveyouitemLOVERpngLOVEReverpngitemitemitem
```

`[[:punct:]]` matches the following characters in `C` locale:

```
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
```

Comment: sorry maybe i'm not understand... how i will write in bash script..

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your "A" string is saved in a file called input.xml:

```
sed -e 's/<item></<item>LOVER.png;LOVER-ever.png</' input.xml
```

This inserts the string "LOVER.png;LOVER-ever.png" into the first "empty" <item></item> on the line, transforming your A string into your B string.

Note that parsing and manipulation XML or HTML or similar structured data files with regular expressions is unreliable at best (and even then only in the very simplest of cases).  For reliable results, an XML parser or similar should be used.  and valid XML too.

Comment: this solution is not good because my file there are many row 1000 lines, there are many "item".. are you sure for use this?

Comment: you should more accurately describe your requirements in your question.  it you don't tell us important factors, we have no way of knowing them.

Comment: XML parsers can handle long files just fine. Give us some example XML  and we can give an answer.

Comment: anonymous downvoter: if you're going to downvote, at least have the courtesy to explain why.